# How do I change multiple anchor tag text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this anchor tag seven times in my html page:

```
<a class="collapsible" style="cursor: pointer;"><span>read more</span></a>
```

and script is like this:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.previousElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      coll[i].innerText="read more";    //if I use coll[0] then it works for first element, but I want to use it for multiple elements
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      coll[i].innerText="read less";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually, you need to change text inside the `span`, which is inside `a`

Comment: Why use `coll` to access the element anyway? You already used `this` to access the element to toggle its class and to get its previous sibling, so why switch to some different method of access now a few lines later?

Comment: @TechySharnav correct, and it's working when I am using coll[0] "Coll with 0 index or some other index". but I want to do it for multiple element at same time.

Comment: thanks @CBroe for suggestion, just needed to replace coll[i] with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.previousElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      this.innerText="read more";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      this.innerText="read less";
    }
  });
}
```